# What is a nice way to keep document.body fullscreen while navigating to another page?

Tags: javascript, html, fullscreen

So I have this website I made for fun a while back: [fakebsod.com](http://fakebsod.com)

I made it so clicking on the first block in the instructions makes the browser go full screen using a function `toggleFullScreen(elem)`. This is called on document.body. My issue is that I want a person to be able to click on the first block and then on the second and still be in fullscreen mode.

I don't want really want to use AJAX or anything like that to load the http://fakebsod.com/generic page so what is a nice way of keeping the page fullscreen?

I can't use parameters or anything as the browsers requires a user to trigger `toggleFullScreen` via a click or action (I can't just call it).

So any idea on how I can do this?
(Yes I know going fullscreen manually is easy but I want to do this anyway).

Comment: I would keep the source of http://fakebsod.com/generic inside your landing page and once you get into full-screen mode then hide the instructions and reveal the BSOD

Comment: Why do you need it to be in a seperate page? You can do this easly by hiding and showing elements in the same page

Comment: And I could fetch the page and display it as well. I am aware of those solutions. I was just wondering if there was a way to seamlessly keep the browser in full screen mode.